# Material-ui select grouping

Tags: material-ui

I'm trying to create a select with ListItems in toggle-able groups. The issues I'm running into are that the select menu closes when toggling the group and I can't get the value of the selected item.

```
handleDropdown = () => {
    this.setState({ showReports: !this.state.showReports })
  }

    <Select
      value={this.state.report}
      onChange={this.handleReportChange}
    >
    <List component="nav">
      <ListItem button>
        <ListItemText inset primary="Sent mail" />
      </ListItem>
    <ListItem button>
      <ListItemText inset primary="Drafts" />
    </ListItem>
    <ListItem button onClick={this.handleDropdown}>
      <ListItemText inset primary="Inbox" />
      {this.state.showReports ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
    </ListItem>
    <Collapse in={this.state.showReports} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
      <List component="div">
        {this.state.reportList.map((report) => (
        <ListItem button value={report.name} key={report.name} className={classes.nested}>
           <ListItemText inset primary={report.displayName} />
        </ListItem>))
       }
     </List>
   </Collapse>
 </List>  
</Select>
```